# VBA Run-time error: '459' External exception when running userform with custom ActiveX control

Tags: c#, .net, vba, excel

I have created a custom ActiveX control in C# by creating a simple COM-Visible class. I am able to build my C# solution and I can see the control in Excel 2010 (32-bit) and I can add my custom control to the VBA userform and see it properly. I am running Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise. However, when I try to run the UserForm, VBA throws `Run-time error '459': External exception`.

You can see from the picture below, that I have successfully added my custom control to the UserForm (just a simple button):

[image]

I can actually click on the button inside my ActiveX control and it will fire a OnButtonClick event that shows up a messagebox:

[image]

The control is also available under additional controls, which allows me to see it in the VBA toolbox:

[image]

I have tried numeruous solutions, but nothing has worked so far, I am simply unable to use my custom control in the VBA UserForm. Here is what I have tried so far:

- using RegAsm.exe "Control DLL Path" /codebase for both 64 and 32-bit
- tried RegAsm.exe without /codebase
- using RegAsm.exe first for 32-bit, then 64-bit, using it only with 32-bit, and only with 64-bit
- added reference under Tools/References in VBA editor to my custom user control class, this now allows me to see the exposed COM interface with methods etc., this now throws     `'459' Object or class does not support the set of events`
- my project has COM-Visible ticked under properties/build and also under assembly information/make assembly COM-Visible

I have also tried using my code on a Windows 10 64-bit machine with Excel 2016 64-bit. I can build the solution, but the control is not visible under additional controls in VBA. I have performed all the RegAsm commands for registering the DLL file, but it will simply not show up there. This is super strange behavior. I am trying to create an ActiveX control that will work on both 32 and 64-bit Excel, since the 32-bit existing VBA controls (we need ListView, DateTimePicker) are not supported in the 64-bit version of Office. We have a large codebase that we cannot switch from VBA to a different platform and we are migrating from 32 to 64-bit systems. I am unable to find a more elegant solution than my current one, it would be ideal, but it behaves in such weird way and refuses to work.

Here is my C# code (it is garbage, just made a quick testing solution), followed a sample that I have found, this is the only solution that actually allows me to add the control to the userform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ActiveXTest2
{
    [ProgId("ActiveXTest2.CustomUserControl")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IUserControlEvents))]
    public partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private ListView listView1;

        public CustomUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // register COM ActiveX object
        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void RegisterClass(string key)
        {
            StringBuilder skey = new StringBuilder(key);
            skey.Replace(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "");

            Type myType1 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ActiveXTest2.CustomUserControl");
            Console.WriteLine("ProgID=ActiveXTest2.CustomUserControl GUID={0}.", myType1.GUID);

            TextWriter tw = File.CreateText("guid.txt");
            tw.WriteLine(skey.ToString());
            tw.WriteLine(myType1.GUID.ToString());
            tw.Close();

            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(skey.ToString(), true);
            RegistryKey ctrl = regKey.CreateSubKey("Control");
            ctrl.Close();
            RegistryKey inprocServer32 = regKey.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", true);
            inprocServer32.SetValue("CodeBase", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            inprocServer32.Close();
            regKey.Close();
        }

        // Unregister COM ActiveX object
        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void UnregisterClass(string key)
        {
            StringBuilder skey = new StringBuilder(key);
            skey.Replace(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "");
            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(skey.ToString(), true);
            regKey.DeleteSubKey("Control", false);
            RegistryKey inprocServer32 = regKey.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", true);
            regKey.DeleteSubKey("CodeBase", false);
            regKey.Close();
        }

        public delegate void ControlEventHandler();

        [Guid("0A415E38-372F-45fb-813B-D9558C787EB0")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        public interface IUserControlEvents
        {
            [DispId(0x60020001)]
            void OnButtonClick();
        }

        public interface ICOMCallable
        {
            int TestValue();
        }

        public int TestValue()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public event ControlEventHandler OnButtonClick;

        protected virtual void OnOnButtonClick()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // listView1
            // 
            this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4);
            this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
            this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 210);
            this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            // 
            // CustomUserControl
            // 
            this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
            this.Name = "CustomUserControl";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(235, 217);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnOnButtonClick();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: So basically the control works on x32 OS, but fails on x64?

Comment: You did not read the entire thing. It shows up in the VBA toolbox under additional controls on x32, but it still does not work, I can only pull it on the UserForm, but when running, it won't run, as it throws exception. On x64 it does not even show up under additional controls.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at this example [create an activeX using cSharp](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/comcom/article.php/c16257/Create-an-ActiveX-using-a-Csharp-Usercontrol.htm)

he had comRegister wrong. i have used the following code to register the COM and it worked.

```
        [ComRegisterFunction()]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type _type)
    {
        if (_type != null)
        {
            string sCLSID = "CLSID\\" + _type.GUID.ToString("B");
            try
            {
                RegistryKey _key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sCLSID, true);
                try
                {
                    Guid _libID = Marshal.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(_type.Assembly);
                    int _major, _minor;
                    Marshal.GetTypeLibVersionForAssembly(_type.Assembly, out _major, out _minor);
                    using (RegistryKey _sub = _key.CreateSubKey("Control")) { }
                    using (RegistryKey _sub = _key.CreateSubKey("MiscStatus")) { _sub.SetValue("", "0", RegistryValueKind.String); }
                    using (RegistryKey _sub = _key.CreateSubKey("TypeLib")) { _sub.SetValue("", _libID.ToString("B"), RegistryValueKind.String); }
                    using (RegistryKey _sub = _key.CreateSubKey("Version")) { _sub.SetValue("", String.Format("{0}.{1}", _major, _minor), RegistryValueKind.String); }
                    using (RegistryKey _sub = _key.CreateSubKey("Control")) { }
                    using (RegistryKey _sub = _key.CreateSubKey("InprocServer32")) { _sub.SetValue("", Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\" + _sub.GetValue("", "mscoree.dll"), RegistryValueKind.String); }
                }
                finally
                {
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction()]
    public static void UnregisterClass(Type t) //(string key)
    {
        string keyName = @"CLSID\" + t.GUID.ToString("B");
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKeyTree(keyName);
        //StringBuilder skey = new StringBuilder(key);
        //skey.Replace(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "");
        //RegistryKey regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(skey.ToString(), true);
        //regKey.DeleteSubKey("Control", false);
        //RegistryKey inprocServer32 = regKey.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", true);
        //regKey.DeleteSubKey("CodeBase", false);
        //regKey.Close();
    }
```